# How to copy tableOutput to clipboard?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to copy the table output to the clipboard on a click of a button. I tried looking into the rclipboard package, but it doesn't appear to be able to copy output, in my limited understanding.

[image]

I added an `actionButton` with an icon to the screenshot to show what I'm trying to achieve. Right now the button doesn't do anything.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars

  one <- function(.data, var, na = TRUE) {
      return({
        .data %>% 
          group_by(.data[[var]]) %>% 
          filter(!is.na(.data[[var]])) %>%
          tally() %>% 
          mutate(`%` = 100*n/sum(n))
        
      })
}
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("var", label = "Select Variable", choices = c("", names(df))),
     tableOutput("value")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    

    output$value <- renderTable({ 
      if(input$var != '') {
        data <- df %>% one(input$var, na = input$check)
        return(data)
        }
    }, spacing = "xs",  bordered = TRUE)
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `copy` button from `DT` to copy the whole table.  You can also copy only selected rows.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

df <- mtcars

one <- function(.data, var, na = TRUE) {
  return({
    .data %>% 
      group_by(.data[[var]]) %>% 
      filter(!is.na(.data[[var]])) %>%
      tally() %>% 
      mutate(`%` = 100*n/sum(n))
    
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("var", label = "Select Variable", choices = c("", names(df))),
  DTOutput("valu", width = "15%")
  #tableOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$valu <- renderDT({
    if(input$var != '') {
      data <- df %>% one(input$var, na = input$check)
      
      DT::datatable(data, 
                    class = 'cell-border stripe',
                    rownames = FALSE,
                    extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),
                    selection = 'none',
                    options = 
                      list(
                        select = TRUE,
                        dom = "Bt",  ##  remove f to remove search  ## Brftip
                        buttons = list(
                          list(
                            extend = "copy",
                            text = 'Copy'#,
                            #exportOptions = list(modifier = list(selected = TRUE))
                          )
                        )
                      )) %>% formatStyle(
                        0,
                        target = "row",
                        fontWeight = styleEqual(1, "bold")
                      ) 
    }
    
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  output$value <- renderTable({ 
    if(input$var != '') {
      data <- df %>% one(input$var, na = input$check)
      return(data)
    }
  },  spacing = "xs",  bordered = TRUE)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: This is great! Can I do the same without DT? I like the simple tableOutput styling.

Comment: And is it possible to copy the entire table all at once without having to select each row? I really appreciate your help, sorry if I keep asking a lot of follow-up questions. I can perhaps ask a new question instead.

Comment: @TyperWriter, please try the updated code.